# javascript regex for MM/YYYY and YYYY

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 2 places I need to regex in javascript
 1 to validate a `MM/YYYY` for that I have:

```
var regEx = new RegExp(/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(\d{4})$/);
```

The other is to validate `YYYY`

I need both to also validate the year is between 1900 and the current year

Comment: Expressing 'not greater than current year' part in regex is, well, tricky. Why don't you just validate it with generic pattern, then check matched year for being between 1900 and current year?

Comment: Take a step back and ask yourself why "regex" earned a place in the question title. It doesn't deserve one.

Comment: Using regex for this is bad idea, parse and do the validation directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for the next millennium:

```
var y = (new Date().getYear()-100).toString(); // "13"
var strReg = '^((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/)?(19\\d{2}|2' + (y.length-2?'':'0');
for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++) {
    strReg+='[0-'+y[i]+']';
}
strReg+=')$'; // "^((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/)?(19\d{2}|20[0-1][0-3])$"
console.log(new RegExp(strReg).test('2013')); // true
console.log(new RegExp(strReg).test('2016')); // false
console.log(new RegExp(strReg).test('01/2013')); // true
console.log(new RegExp(strReg).test('13/2013')); // false
```

And if you want to use valid dates from this century and the last century (versus 1900s til now), you can replace 19 in the regex with this code... `'...?(' + (y.length-2?parseInt(y[0])+19:'19') + '\\d{2}|...'`

Answer (score 1):

make a regex for mm it should be like

```
/0([1-9])|1([1-2])/
```

and for yyyy it should be like

```
/(19\d{2})|(200\d)|(201[0-3])/
```

you can make a single regex to check mm/yyyy like

```
/0([1-9])|1([1-2])\/(19\d{2})|(200\d)|(201[0-3])/
```

then use the loop to validate the year and month you want to check